# In python 3 Compare different rows of 2 different csv files and create new csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Here is the scenario.
I have 2 csv files as follows:

CSV FILE 1 (previousmembers.csv):

```
john.doe@mydomain.com
suzy.smith@mydomain.com
test.person@mydomain.com
another.person@mydomain.com
cool.guy@mydomain.com
```

CSV FILE 2 (updatedmembers.csv):

```
1234,password1,John,Mike,Doe,2022,john.doe@mydomain.com
83762,password2,Suzy,Sally,Smith,2022,suzy.smith@mydomain.com
91209,password3,Test,Kid,Person,2023,test.person@mydomain.com
671653,password4,Cool,Tom,Guy,2027,cool.guy@mydomain.com
82637,password5,New,Billy,Kid,2026,new.kid@mydomain.com
956656,password6,Another,New,Newbie,2027,another.newbie@mydomain.com
```

Desired output (newfolks.csv):

```
82637,password5,New,Billy,Kid,2026,new.kid@mydomain.com
956656,password6,Another,New,Newbie,2027,another.newbie@mydomain.com
```

Here is what I have so far, and its not even close to working:

```
with open('previousmembers.csv') as check_file:
    check_set = set([row[0] for row in check_file])


with open('updatedmembers.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('newfolks.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    check_set2 = set([row[6] for row in in_file])
    for line in check_set2:
        if line not in check_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```

The idea is that I want to create a csv file that has every line from updatedmembers.csv where row[6] of updatedmembers.csv does NOT exist in previousmembers.csv. (previusmembers.csv will only ever have an email listed, which is why I need to compare row[6] of updatedmembers.csv

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the row with `another.newbie@mydomain.com` is in your output? In csv file 1 you don't have this email.

Comment: @AndrejKesely The idea is that I want to create a csv file that has every line from updatedmembers.csv where row[6] of updatedmembers.csv does NOT exist in previousmembers.csv. (previusmembers.csv will only ever have an email listed, which is why i need to compare row[6] of updatedmembers.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not processing the comma separated values into a list. You would typically use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for this, which will handle edge cases nicely and makes some things simpler. But if you are just learning, you can use `split(',')` to split the values. After you do that, you can then index and get words. For example:

```
with open('previousmembers.csv') as check_file:
    # no need to index here, it's just one string per line
    # strip whitespace to be sure there's no junk
    check_set = set(row.strip() for row in check_file)


with open('updatedmembers.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('newfolks.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        # split on commas (or use csv module)
        fields = line.split(',')
        if fields[6].strip() not in check_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```

This will write these rows to the new file:

```
82637,password5,New,Billy,Kid,2026,new.kid@mydomain.com
956656,password6,Another,New,Newbie,2027,another.newbie@mydomain.com
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to do it with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_1 = pd.DataFrame(['john.doe@mydomain.com',
'suzy.smith@mydomain.com',
'test.person@mydomain.com',
'another.person@mydomain.com',
'cool.guy@mydomain.com'])

# csv_1 = pd.read_csv('previousmembers.csv')

csv_1.columns = ['email_csv1']

csv_2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1234,'password1','John','Mike','Doe',2022,'john.doe@mydomain.com'],
[83762,'password2','Suzy','Sally','Smith',2022,'suzy.smith@mydomain.com'],
[91209,'password3','Test','Kid','Person',2023,'test.person@mydomain.com'],
[671653,'password4','Cool','Tom','Guy',2027,'cool.guy@mydomain.com'],
[82637,'password5','New','Billy','Kid',2026,'new.kid@mydomain.com'],
[956656,'password6','Another','New','Newbie',2027,'another.newbie@mydomain.com']
])

# csv_2 = pd.read_csv('updatedmembers.csv')

csv_2.columns = ['id', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'person_type', 'year', 'email_csv2']

csv_3 = csv_2.merge(csv_1, how="left", left_on='email_csv2', right_on='email_csv1')

newfolks = csv_3.loc[csv_3.email_csv1.isna()][csv_2.columns]

new_folks.to_csv('new_folks.csv')
```

Basically, do a left join from csv2 to csv1 on email field. Then select the rows in csv2 which don't have a corresponding email in csv1 and we're done.